# Count number of word occurrences in strings using XQuery

Tags: xquery

We have a very similar XML file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodeOne>
  <nodeTwo>
    <nodeThree>
      foo bar zoo
    </nodeThree>
  </nodeTwo>
</nodeOne>
<nodeOne>
  <nodeTwo>
    <nodeThree>
      foo bar
    </nodeThree>      
  </nodeTwo>
</nodeOne>
<nodeOne>
  <nodeTwo>
    <nodeThree>
      zoo bar
    </nodeThree>      
  </nodeTwo>
</nodeOne>
```

What I would like to achieve is to count the occurrences of every word (delimitered by a whitespace) inside `nodeThree`. Considering the above example, the output would be something like:

```
foo 2
bar 3
zoo 2
```

I've tried to fetch every `text()` of `nodeThree`, and tried to `tokenize()` it into sequences of strings. Then, I thought, I might be able to join them and group, count afterwards, but I was not able to do so. Tried a lot of things until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that your XML is ill-formed (i.e. it's not really XML) unless you create a single root node to wrap it.

If performance is a concern, this problem is much better suited to leverage a word index with frequency data, like in an XML database. Solving this in pure XQuery may be considerably slower for large XML but solves the problem:

```
let $xml :=
    <root>
    <nodeOne>
      <nodeTwo>
        <nodeThree>
          foo bar zoo
        </nodeThree>
      </nodeTwo>
    </nodeOne>
    <nodeOne>
      <nodeTwo>
        <nodeThree>
          foo bar
        </nodeThree>      
      </nodeTwo>
    </nodeOne>
    <nodeOne>
      <nodeTwo>
        <nodeThree>
          zoo bar
        </nodeThree>      
      </nodeTwo>
    </nodeOne>
    </root>
let $toks := $xml//text()/fn:tokenize(fn:normalize-space(.),'\s')
for $t in distinct-values($toks)
let $count := count($toks[. = $t])
return element { $t } {
    attribute count { $count }
} 
=>
<foo count="2"/>
<bar count="3"/>
<zoo count="2"/>
```